# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-calendar

I have used sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.js on a page.

Page contains Calendar view web part.Calendar list contains events, but events are not displayed on the calendar web part page.

Page shows error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null** .

Comment: This happen when DOM is not ready. try to put your ``sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.js`` reference in the last of the HTML page and then check.

Comment: @akshay any luck on this issue?

Comment: did you ever resolved this error?